# How to call another method inside of the main method?

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I am trying to call a method, readAndFill(); in my main method. I am getting an error message saying " readAndFill cannot be applied to given types. readAndFill is a method to just put numbers into an array.

I've renaming the method, putting readAndFill(double[]array, int numOfNumbers) instead of readAndFill();.

```
package program9;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class Program9 {
static void readAndFill(double[]array, int numOfNumbers) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    for(int i=0;i < numOfNumbers; i++){
        System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
        array[i] = keyboard.nextDouble();
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int numOfNumbers;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    double arrayNumbers;
    System.out.print("How many numbers will be read in the array?: 
");
    numOfNumbers = keyboard.nextInt();
    double[] array = new double[numOfNumbers];
```

```
        readAndFill();
```

```
}
static void readAndFill(double[]array, int numOfNumbers) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    for(int i=0;i < numOfNumbers; i++){
        System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
        array[i] = keyboard.nextDouble();
    }
}
```

Comment: You're not passing any arguments to your method.

Comment: I'm not necessarily trying to pass any argument to my mine method. What I need to do is define an array so that all of my other methods can use it.

Comment: You need to have a way so that the inputs you have you provide them to your method. your method signature has arguments so it expects them when being invoked. You have to pass parameters while invoking method

Comment: As everyone has already said, pass your arguments to the method. Change `readAndFill();` to `readAndFill(array, numOfNumbers);`

Comment: Ah okay I see now. I didn't know the proper syntax. I had tried readAndFill(array[], numOfNumbers); but not without the square brackets.

Answer (score 0):

readAndFill methods need two parameter. 
Replace the method call in main() with below.

readAndFill(array , numOfNumbers);

Answer (score 0):

call your function this way `readAndFill(array , numOfNumbers);`